# Laravel validation always returns 200 OK from API

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to separate my validator with my controller, but API always responds with a `200 OK` in Postman.

**Request validation**:

```php
class PostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use Types;

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        // $auth = $this->request->user();
        return [
            'name'       => 'required|string|max:255',
            'country_id' => 'required|exists:countries,id',
            'city'       => 'required|max:255',
            'phone_no'   => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{10,13}/',
            'occupation' => 'required|max:255'
        ];
    }
}
```

**SenderController**:

```php
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
    $auth = $request->user();

    $sender = Sender::create([
        'name'          => $request->name,
        'country_id'    => $request->country_id,
        'city'          => $request->city,
        'phone_no'      => $request->phone_no,
        'occupation'    => $request->occupation
    ]);
    return new Resource($sender);
}
```

When I'm sending a request without `name`, it will return a response with a status of 200. I want to display `$validator->errors()` in my response when I forget to input name. How can I do that?

[image: Postman]

**Route and call**:

```php
Route::post('sender', 'V1\SenderController@store');

POST: localhost:8000/api/v1/sender
```

Comment: can you share screenshot of postman

Comment: I have posted the screenshot @ShaielndraGupta

Comment: What does "separate my validator with my controller" mean?

Comment: I mean that usually I am using validation in my controller, but now, I want to try to separate the file like I am doing right now @emotality

Comment: So inject a normal `Request` instead of `PostRequest`, no? Btw, if your keys are the same like it is now, you can just `Sender::create($request->all());` or `Sender::create($request->only(['key1', 'key2']));` no need to recreate the same structure. :)

Comment: I am using PostRequest because I need to make the documentation with using laravel api documentation generator, and to generate it, I have to separate it.. That's why I decide to separate the validator with the controller @emotality

Comment: What does the trait `Types` in your request ? Did you try without?

Comment: When a FormRequest validator fails, it redirects you back to the form with the errors injected within it (so you'll have an `errors` bag containing all of the validation errors). I think that the issue is that it's trying to redirect you back to a form that doesn't exist, since your request has no origin, landing you back in the front page (`/`)... but other than that, the `FormRequest` seems fine to me.

Comment: do you have any idea? @JaimeRojas

Comment: @JamesRiady I suggest one of the following: Either try out the Validator on a browser (which should properly redirect you since you'd be coming from a form), or override the `failedValidation` method in the PostRequest to `dd` or `dump` the errors, which should show on the request response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem with adding more code in my `PostRequest.php`

```
public $validator = null;
protected function failedValidation($validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

and I show the error message by using controller

```
if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'error_code'=> 'VALIDATION_ERROR', 
            'message'   => 'The given data was invalid.', 
            'errors'    => $request->validator->errors()
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 46):

You should make sure you're sending the request with the `Accept: application/json` header.

Without that - Laravel won't detect that it's an API request, and won't generate the 422 response with errors.

Comment: ^ This should be the  accepted answer. Many tools like Postman, Insomnia etc ... may not add this header for you by default. Double check it.

Answer (score 11):

If you are requesting from postman then always check header and set

```
Accept = 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to display validation errors using injected `FormRequest` object is to override `failedValidation`.

As stated previously in comment section, injected `FormRequest` object validates the request by itself, no need to validate it a second time in the controller body (that's one of the main benefit of it). If the validation fails, you won't hit the controller body anyway.

Create an abstract class that extends `FormRequest` and override `failedValidation`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

abstract class BaseFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    abstract public function rules(): array;

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    abstract public function authorize(): bool;

    /**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     *
     * @param  Validator  $validator
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator): void
    {
        $errors = $validator->errors();

        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
            'errors' => $errors
        ], Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
    }
}
```

You can now extends `BaseFormRequest` on all your APIs request validation classes. Validation errors will now be displayed as a JSON encoded message with a Unprocessable Entity (422) HTTP code.

Source : https://medium.com/@Sirolad/laravel-5-5-api-form-request-validation-errors-d49a85cd29f2

Answer (score 1):

Your Postman response is sending back the `welcome.blade.php` default view. This means that it isn't hitting your controller method, as the method returns the `Resource` instance. This means that the validator won't be run.

Check that the route you are making the request to is definitely the correct route. Also check that you are making a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request.

Comment: you are right, it calls my welcome.blade.php.. but if I pass the validation, it will call the actual API

Comment: It's not hitting the validation at all. Can you post your routes, the url you are making the request to and the request method.

Comment: so, what should I do to make it hitting the validation?

Comment: I can see you have added the route. What is the URL you are posting to in Postman? It's more than likely that the URL you are making the request to is wrong.

Comment: Is the route within an `api` prefix route group? If not, then you don't need the `api` in the url you are requesting. Try changing your route from `Route::post('sender', 'V1\SenderController@store');` to `Route::post('api/v1/sender', 'V1\SenderController@store');`

Comment: the problem is not in the route, If I am using `Request $request` as the parameter, it will work.. the problem is why when I am using `PostRequest`, it does not get the validation

Comment: Oh, in your headers make sure you are sending Content-Type: application/json otherwise it won’t get processed as an Ajax request.

Answer (score -2):

you have to validate your request before saving

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
    $auth = $request->validate();

    if($auth->fails())
    {
         return response()->json($auth->errors());
    }
    $sender = Sender::create([
        'name'          => $request->name,
        'country_id'    => $request->country_id,
        'city'          => $request->city,
        'phone_no'      => $request->phone_no,
        'occupation'    => $request->occupation
    ]);
     return new Resource($sender);

}
```

Comment: If you method inject a FormRequest object, it will do the validation automatically.

Comment: why it'll di validation automatically is it in constructer..? @GeorgeHanson

Comment: Can you quote the documentation please? I've never seen this and always used `->validated()`

Comment: See here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: I don't know why if I miss one of the required field, it will pass my route

Comment: you are using this route for your web or API..??

Comment: @emotality the validated method is used to retrieve the input data which has been validated, not to run the validation process.

Comment: @GeorgeHanson just tested your theory and it seems to be true :) thanks!